# How to make change gcc calling convention

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, calling-convention, abi

Hi I would like to tell gcc how to call functions, for example:

```c
    __mycall void my_function(arg1) {
        do_something(arg1)
    }
```

```
    __mycall:
        move $a0, (the first argument)
        jalr (the function we should call)
        nop
```

I would like the generated assembly code of:

```c
    my_function(1);
```

To be

```
    move $a0, 1
    jalr my_function
    nop
```

I obviously don't want to implement stdcall or fastcall or something like that, i just explained by an example.

I don't think it should be hard to do that but I don't find any example on how to do that
I can write inline assembly and call my function with inline assembly but it is ugly, I will appreciate help (:

Comment: Have you tried checking the assembly generated by the compiler when you turn on optimization flags? The compiler might do this automatically for you if you allow it to optimize.

Comment: I'm not trying to optimize my code, I'm trying to force the compiler to call my function in a certain way, for example in x86 there is libc_get_pc_tunk function or something like that to get the instruction pointer, -Fpie is implemented in gcc to generate a pic code. but if it didn't using this method we can calculate the absolute address of the function then call it eg... *(get_pc_thunk() + relative_address_of_function)(arg1, arg2, arg3) I want to implement something like that and for that, I would like to write my own assembly and make it call functions how i want

Comment: So, if I understand you right, you want, that instead of RCX,RDX,R8,R9, for example the calling convention now is(For example): RAX,RBX,RCX,RDX?

Comment: exactly, I'm only calling my code like that so it should be fine I'm not going to call library functions

Comment: I would guess, it is impossible without modifying the compiler

Comment: Taking a closer look at GCC I found this file: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libffi/src/x86/sysv.S declaring how to call a function in x86 (ffi_call_i386), so i may need to compile my own GCC, but i'm sure there is a better way to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use fastcall or thiscall function attribute (x86-32)

On x86-32 targets, the fastcall attribute causes the compiler to pass the first argument (if of integral type) in the register ECX and the second argument (if of integral type) in the register EDX. Subsequent and other typed arguments are passed on the stack. The called function pops the arguments off the stack. If the number of arguments is variable all arguments are pushed on the stack.

On x86-32 targets, the thiscall attribute causes the compiler to pass the first argument (if of integral type) in the register ECX. Subsequent and other typed arguments are passed on the stack. The called function pops the arguments off the stack. If the number of arguments is variable all arguments are pushed on the stack. The thiscall attribute is intended for C++ non-static member functions. As a GCC extension, this calling convention can be used for C functions and for static member methods.